# webflux bodyToMono code block not getting called

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am having following code, which is not being called, I tried it debugging it, but the code is not getting called in any way.

```
private Mono<ServerResponse> validateRequestData(ServerRequest serverRequest)
{
 return serverRequest.bodyToMono(this.validationClass)
  .flatMap(body -> {
   Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(body,this.validationClass.getName());
   this.validator.validate(body, errors);
   if (!errors.getAllErrors().isEmpty()) {
   return onValidationErrors(errors, body, serverRequest);
}
  return Mono.empty();
 });
```

}

Anything I am missing in this?

Please guide,
Regards,
Gaurav

I tried debugging it, this code is actually meant for validating the Server Request from the POST call from postman.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. "Code is not getting called" is too broad. be specific, please.